# Multiple touch location in iOS?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uitouch, uievent

I want to get two touch point on multitouch. I am touching and holding one point then after i touch second point on screen. Then touches moved method called but both time i get the frirst touch location.I am not geting second touch position in touches moved method.

Answer (score 0):

The second location should make itself known via a touchesBegan event. In your UIView you need to have public methods for the OS to call, and one of them is `(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. touchesMoved will only list existing touches. If you move both touch points, later calls of touchesMoved should list pointers to both touches in the NSSet *touches.

It will be easier to help if you post the relevant part of your code. Please edit your question.